# A simple yet confusing ARIMA

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima

If I used `arima(data, c(1,0,1))` in R software and get this result:

[image: R Output]

How should I write the equation for $ARMA(1,1)$ or $ARIMA(1,0,1)$?
Is the following correct?

$$
y_t=18.7083+0.8672y_{t-1}+0.4752\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
$$

Comment: Regarding the interpretation of the intercept (`18.7083`), you have likely got it wrong. See https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm. I also think the sign of MA should be inverted.

Comment: So, from the reference and from what you said $y_t=2.4826+0.8673y_{t-1}-0.4752\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$. Will this be correct?

Comment: How did you arrive at 2.4826?

Comment: $18.7083(1-0.8673)=2.4826$ That is based on the page you linked.

Comment: I suppose it is OK then. And if so, you could write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what *Richard Hardy* pointed out, the fitted $ARIMA(1,0,1)$ can be written as
$$
y_t=2.4826+0.8673y_{t-1}-0.4752\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
$$
is the correct answer.